# Как решить C:\fakepath

Tags: javascript

Как отправить txt (или любой другой) файл на сервер указывая правильный путь?

На данный момент я отправляю вот так

```
form.append("file",new File(["file"], document.getElementById("file").value, {
   type: "text/plain",
}));
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="add-file" class="file" />
```

Такой подход у меня показывает вот этот путь что не правильно

```
C:\fakepath\test.txt
```

Но мне надо правильно указать путь  чтобы все работало.Надо указать абсолютный путь  вот так `/C:/Users/Max/Desktop/test.txt`

Comment: Никак. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Comment: Никак. JS в браузере не имеет доступа к файловой системе.

Comment: @Yaant ну как  тогда мне отправить файл на сервак ?Вот так __C:\fakepath\test.txt__ что ли?

Comment: Зачем вам на сервере знать полный путь к файлу на клиенте?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko из за того что читать из него данные.

Comment: В смысле? У Вас есть `<input type="file" ... />`. Вот содержимое этого инпута и отправляйте, какой там реальный путь, Вас не должно заботить от слова "совсем". Программно прочитать произвольный файл из файловой системы Вы не сможете. Можете только выбрать его руками, через `<input>`.

Comment: То есть вы хотите с сервера, который условно находится где-то в Америке, открыть на чтение файл находящийся на клиентском компьютере где-то в России?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения задачи делается немного по другому! Вы загружаете файл через `input`. Далее отправляете его на сервер ( кнопка `submit` или ajax с предварительно сформированным `FormData`). На сервер приходит временный путь хранения данного файла! (fake как у вас указан) Далее средствами серверного языка Вы сохраняете файл в файловой системе сервера и записываете путь в бд или куда хотите, или сразу получаете данные из файла и отправляете на клиент и после удаляете файл с сервера, делаете любые манипуляции. Если бы было как Вы хотите сделать, то любой паренёк смог отправив вам js файл получить любые данные с компьютера без Вашего ведома, просто считав их из файловой системы!