# Что делать с C:\fakepath?

Tags: javascript, html, файлы, input, файловые-пути

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы получить путь к файлу через file.value

```js
function view_path() {
  // получаю айди элементов
  let file = document.getElementById("file");
  let view = document.getElementById("view");
  // задаю путь из элемента с файлом в элемент с путём
  view.value = file.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" /><button onclick="view_path()">показать</button>
<br>
<text>ваш путь:</text>
<br>
<input id="view" readonly value="не выбрано" />
```

но получаю C:\fakepath\название_файла.txt.
как решить?

Comment: Возможно ответ тут - https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.292bbb90-65a92c8c-d2f1858d-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using%20%20-jav

Comment: Никак. Веб-страница не должна знать ничего про файлы на файловой системе.

Comment: @Alexey Ten а есть способ чтобы открыть файл в iframe?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как решить C:\fakepath](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989058/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-c-fakepath)

Comment: А зачем тебе получать путь к файлу? Для получения содержимого - путь не нужен

Comment: Есть некая функция [`document.requestStorageAccess()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/requestStorageAccess). Сказать честно ни разу не пользовался, но по описанию вроде то, что вы ищите. Может поможет.

Comment: @eccs0103, а какое описание ты смотришь у функции _document.requestStorageAccess()_?

Comment: @Grundy `The requestStorageAccess() method of the Document interface allows content loaded in a third-party context (i.e., embedded in an <iframe>) to request access to third-party cookies.`

Comment: @eccs0103, И как это относится к инпуту?

Comment: Так а что хочется сделать? Получить путь или отобразить текст из файла? Если отобразить текст, то посмотрите https://learn.javascript.ru/file